# Can you explain why is there zero voltage at the source of a differiential MOSFET amplifier?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, circuit-analysis, differential

Using KVL, KCL and circuit analysis, Can you explain why is there zero voltage at the source of a differiential MOSFET amplifier?
In the textbook, they just state that because it's balanced the source is zero.
[image]

Comment: Where's the power supply? Without that everything will be at zero volts except, perhaps, the FET gates but they're insulated and won't feed current into the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the caption this is a small-signal analysis.

The inputs of the amplifier are driven differentially, when one is driven with a positive voltage the other is driven with a negative voltage of the same magnitude but opposite sign.

For this reason when for example Q1 is driven with vid/2 we have a current gm*vid/2 flowing downwards through this transistor. At the same time Q2 is driven with -vid/2 and the same current is flowing upwards through Q2.

So even if there was conductance from the "virtual ground" node to another node there would be no current to cause a voltage drop. Hence the small-signal voltage is zero.

Comment: How is current following upwards in a NMOS transistor?

Comment: Since we are doing small-signal analysis, we set every DC component to zero. Assuming an initial current of 100uA through each of the transistors, when we drive them such that we have 110uA (=100uA + 10uA) through Q1 and 90uA (100uA - 10uA), then the AC component is what remains after subtracting the DC bias. We get 10uA through Q1 and -10uA through Q2. So the -10uA flow upwards through Q2.